# How to design a diagram/framework to exhibit tool's underlaying structure

Tags: framework, diagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate schemas of GIS hardware / software / workflows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/how-to-generate-schemas-of-gis-hardware-software-workflows)

Can anyone give me some examples of framework diagrams that showcase/exhibit a tool, web-mapping application or similar that use a smorgasbord of interconnected elements, libraries, functions and tools. This is especially useful for communicating how your tool works when speaking publicly (per se) about the tool itself.

I am in the process of creating a poster for an academic conference (GeoIDE Geospatial Conference) and need some help putting my idea onto paper. Note that I may be using the incorrect terminology... feel free to edit!

This is a rudamentary proposal for what I want to display:

```
             DECISION   ALTERNATIVES
                    ↑   ↑
                     MAP <------------- ↰
                     ↑↑↑                 |     
MAPSERVER ----◇-> OPENLAYERS      DECISION MAKER
     JQUERY --↥------------------------ ↵
```

Is there a best practise to this type of diagram/visual aid? What have you come across that helped you design something similar? Any help is appreciated. I'm about to break out the crayons and construction paper!

Comment: You mean like [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)?

Comment: Both of you helped me find what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to write about what you end(ed) up doing as an answer!